# Android Sqlite Count item in each day of the current week

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to count item within each day of the current week.
Unfortunately this select not working i would like...

Thanks for your help

```
SELECT strftime('%d', data_item/1000, 'unixepoch') AS valDay,
    SUM(numero_item) AS totalDAY
FROM table
WHERE
    strftime('%Y', data_item/1000, 'unixepoch') = strftime('%Y', 'now')
    AND strftime('%m', data_item/1000, 'unixepoch') = strftime('%m', 'now')
    GROUP BY valDay

EDIT I've added the solution (localtime) for future reference:
strftime('%Y', data_item/1000, 'unixepoch''localtime') = strftime('%Y', 'now')
```

Comment: I see nothing related to some week in this query. And what definition of "week" are you using?

Answer (score -1):

have you tried it like

```
SELECT strftime('%d', data_item/1000, 'unixepoch') AS valDay,
SUM(numero_item) AS totalDAY
FROM table
WHERE
 strftime('%Y', data_item/1000, 'unixepoch') = strftime('%Y', 'now')
 AND strftime('%m', data_item/1000, 'unixepoch') = strftime('%m', 'now')
 GROUP BY strftime('%d', data_item/1000, 'unixepoch')
```

not all languages support using the aliases ( like valDay )later on in the query

Comment: SQLite does support this.

Comment: Yes thanks I tried, but the records for the day are the same as the previous query.I have to try another type of select, so why do I get the values ​​for that day are not exact. Pleas help..